# C++ why "deque iterator not dereferencable "

Tags: c++

I am doing a sample test given in https://www.testdome.com/for-developers/solve-question/9930

"A TrainComposition is built by attaching and detaching wagons from the left and the right sides. For example, if we start by attaching wagon 7 from the left followed by attaching wagon 13, again from the left, we get a composition of two wagons (13 and 7 from left to right). Now the first wagon that can be detached from the right is 7 and the first that can be detached from the left is 13. Implement a TrainComposition that models this problem."

I modified code by using std::deque, but when I build it, a error happens: "deque iterator not dereferencable". Why this error happens and how to resolve it?

```
    #include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

class TrainComposition
{
    //std::vector<int> wagons;

public:

    std::deque<int> wagons;

    void attachWagonFromLeft(int wagonId)
    {
        wagons.push_front(wagonId);
    }

    void attachWagonFromRight(int wagonId)
    {
        wagons.push_back(wagonId);
    }

    int detachWagonFromLeft()
    {
        std::deque<int>::iterator it = wagons.begin();
        wagons.pop_front();
        return *it;
    }

    int detachWagonFromRight()
    {
        std::deque<int>::iterator it = wagons.end()-1;
        wagons.pop_back();
        return *it;
    }
};

#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    TrainComposition tree;
    tree.attachWagonFromLeft(7);
    tree.attachWagonFromLeft(13);
    std::cout << tree.detachWagonFromRight() << "\n"; // 7 
    std::cout << tree.detachWagonFromLeft() << "\n"; // 13
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

Comment: `wagons.end()` does not point to the last element, it points to one past it. Use `wagons.end() - 1` for that (or `std::prev(wagons.end())`), or just `wagons.back()`.

Comment: now you compile https://ideone.com/ryqArI without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sequence of instructions in `detachWagonFromLeft()` is a problem:

```
std::deque<int>::iterator it = wagons.begin();
wagons.pop_front();
return *it;
```

You save an iterator to the first element but the [`pop_front()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_front) then invalidates that iterator. Dereferencing an invalidated iterator is undefined behavior.

I suggest this simpler version that works:

```
int temp = wagons.front();
wagons.pop_front();
return temp;
```

You have a similar problem in the `detachWagonFromRight()` function that can be fixed as:

```
int temp = wagons.back();
wagons.pop_back();
return temp;
```